# Compilation failed when using the pseudo-union type js.Dictionary[js.Any] | Null

Tags: scala, scala.js

Why does the following statement

```
type properties = js.Dictionary[js.Any] | Null
val foo: properties = js.Dictionary("a"-> 1)
```

report a "type-mismatch" compilation error?

```
ScalaFiddle.scala:6: error: type mismatch;
found   : js.this.Dictionary[scala.this.Int]
required: ScalaFiddle.this.properties
    (which expands to)  js.this.$bar[js.this.Dictionary[js.this.Any],scala.this.Null]
  val foo: properties = js.Dictionary("a"-> 1)
```

The pseudo-union type **properties** is part of a Scala.js facade obtained using the *scala-js-ts-importer*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem lies in the fact that `js.Dictionary("a" -> 1)` results in a `js.Dictionary[Int]`.

As `js.Dictionary[js.Any] <: js.Dictionary[js.Any] | Null` is by definition true,
you can supply a `js.Dictionary[js.Any]` to `foo`,  but `js.Dictionary[Int] <: js.Dictionary[js.Any]` is false.

To fix this, you have to explicitly define the type:

```scala
val foo: properties = js.Dictionary[js.Any]("a"-> 1)
```

[Try it out!](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/8v9bGws/0)

---

I hope this helps.

Comment: The type parameter A in the trait sealed trait Dictionary[A] extends js.Any is invariant. It means that only `js.Any`s are valid for a `js.Dictionary[js.Any]` whilst `Int`s are obviously being invalid. Unfortunately, without the explicit definition, `js.Dictionary("a"->1)` was treated as a `js.Dictionary[Int]` in the original statement, instead of a `js.Dictionary[js.Any]`.